# Google Drive api, how to know if already authenticated?

Tags: c#, authentication, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

So I am using Google.Apis.Drive.v3 on C#.
In this code I am requesting acces to the user's drive.

```
    UserCredential credential;
    try
    {
        using (var stream =
            new System.IO.FileStream ("client_secret.json", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = System.IO.Path.Combine (credPath, ".credentials/drive-hourcounter.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync (
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load (stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore (credPath, true)).Result;
        }
    }
```

My question is, how do I know if the user is already gave me access?
Now I am always running this code, and if no exceptions are thrown then I know that I have access. Is there a better solution? Maybe testing the existence of the ".credentials/drive-hourcounter.json" file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I understand, if your code execution successfully pass through the below and get a Result, then the authorization has been successful.

`GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(...).Result;`

The above will wait indefinitely, if the user does not click on either the Allow or Deny buttons on the web page when prompted. Catching the exception with a try-catch block is a usual way to handle the denial and other unexpected errors (e.g. failure to connect to the Google web site)

if you need to handle the AuthorizeAsync in more advanced manner, you may want to consider using a "async Task" structure in your code. See: https://www.infoq.com/articles/Tasks-Async-Await

---

testing the existence of the ".credentials/drive-hourcounter.json" file is definitely not a good approach as the access can be revoked by the user at https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions without deleting the local file.

Comment: GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync() is passed even when the access is revoke by the user, but it will throw exception when calling service api

Comment: You shouldn't use .Result, because you can have a dead lock, instead use await all the way await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(...)

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need to know if the user has areadly granted you access the client library is handing all of that for you.

If the user doesn't have access then `FileDatastore` will pop up the authentication screen and ask them for it.  `FileDatastore` will then store a file on your machine with the credentials needed by your application to gain access next time without having to ask them.    If the file does not exist then it knows that it needs to prompt for access.   `"user"` is used to differentiate between multiple users.

I have a tutorial that explains how FileDatastore works with regard to the Google .net Client library [Google .net – FileDatastore demystified](http://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/)

This is the method I use.  Its slightly different then yours but not much.

```
/// <summary>
/// This method requests Authentcation from a user using Oauth2.  
/// Credentials are stored in System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal
/// Documentation https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
/// </summary>
/// <param name="clientSecretJson">Path to the client secret json file from Google Developers console.</param>
/// <param name="userName">Identifying string for the user who is being authentcated.</param>
/// <returns>DriveService used to make requests against the Drive API</returns>
public static DriveService AuthenticateOauth(string clientSecretJson, string userName) {
 try {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
   throw new Exception("userName is required.");
  if (!File.Exists(clientSecretJson))
   throw new Exception("clientSecretJson file does not exist.");

  // These are the scopes of permissions you need. It is best to request only what you need and not all of them
  string[] scopes = new string[] {
   DriveService.Scope.Drive
  }; // View and manage the files in your Google Drive

  UserCredential credential;
  using(var stream = new FileStream(clientSecretJson, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
   string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
   credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/apiName");

   // Requesting Authentication or loading previously stored authentication for userName
   credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
    scopes,
    userName,
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
  }

  // Create Drive API service.
  return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
   HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = string.Format("{0} Authentication", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name),
  });
 } catch (Exception ex) {
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("AuthenticateOauth failed: {0}", ex.Message));
  throw new Exception("RequestAuthentcationFailed", ex);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your app gains authorization if user [Allows it in the consent screen](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth).

> 4. If the user approves, then Google gives your application a short-lived access token.
> 5. Your application requests user data, attaching the access token to the request.
> 6. If Google determines that your request and the token are valid, it returns the requested data.

If Google returns the requested data, with respect to your [scope](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth), then that means you are authorized.
However, if you get a [Error 403 message](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors), it means you don't have permission.

Answer (score 0):

To check if credential is existed in local

```
await new FileDataStore(credPath, true).GetAsync<TokenResponse>(userId) != null
```